# Element style.display does not change while alert box is showing

Tags: javascript, css

The following JS function is supposed to make the element "shape" disappear before showing alert but the alert was shown first and "shape" remain. The console log indicates that "shape" style.display was set to "none". How do I make "shape" disappear before showing alert?

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
            var start = new Date().getTime();        
            document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
                console.log(document.getElementById("shape").style.display);
                var end = new Date().getTime();
                var timeTaken = end - start;
                console.log(timeTaken);
                alert(timeTaken);
            }

        </script>
```

Comment: Use a short `setTimeout` for the alert to give the browser time to redraw.

Comment: The browser probably doesn't re-render the DOM before your script ran, and your script only finishes after the `alert`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/jhm7roz8/ alert with timeout (5 secs)

Answer (score 0):

Question is..
What is this shape?    If it's a canvas thing, there is a clear command for it, but if it's an image, there are ways to remove the source and 'hide'  the img tag, if you wanted to.

For things like Divs, & other HTML objects (including just hiding an entire canvas)

```
var example = document.getElementById("shape");
example.style.display = "none";
```

Or to wipe a canvas if you are using it for drawing (HTML5 Canvas)

```
var can = document.getElementById("Shape");
var surface= can.getContext("2d");
surface.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
```

Though, it is alittle unclear what the 'shape' is that you want to clear, or how you want to clear it.

Comment: this answer does not address the question asked of how to delay the alert box. The OP (asker) has already selected how to hide the shape (display:none;)

Comment: The reason I asked, is because it kinda depends on what the object was (some tag, img, or object)

Though, if We're honest the answer depends on what the shape is, and partly that the function wasn't split.

The OP did not answer what the shape was... and if it's what I've seen others do is somehow assign an entire draw function to an object & treat it the same when it's apart of the canvas.

That said, it's likely a conflict with the css if it's a tag or img element, the OP didn't give enough details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the browser time to re-render. Run your `alert()` inside a `setTimeout()`, (even 0ms is enough), to force the `alert()` to run on the next event-ticker.